# Restoring a deletedDirectoryObject (Recycle Bin User) via Azure AD Graph API

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to restore a deletedDirectoryObject (Recycle Bin User) via the Azure AD Graph API. This is part of an application I am developing. I can see the Recycle Bin User via

`GET https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/deletedDirectoryObjects/{upn-or-object-id}`

I can even delete the user by sending an HTTP DELETE to the same url.

`DELETE https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/deletedDirectoryObjects/{upn-or-object-id}`

But, I cannot restore. There is some documentation around storing applications but not users. I have noticed that the Microsoft Graph API has this capability but currently only available on their beta endpoint. Naturally my organization is not interested on building upon the beta end-point.

How can I restore my Recycle Bin User via the Azure Graph API or some other production API?

Note: I know this is possible via PowerShell (Microsoft Online Commandlets) but the application I am building is in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

This is the graph API [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-restore?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) , to restore the deleted directory object